# Using maven profile for artifact versioning

Tags: maven, build, versioning, profile, artifactory

I want a project's version number to be as the follow format for the normal release versioning:

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<version>1.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
......
```

On the other hand, I want to have a built artifact for every change merged like below:

```
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT-${timestamp}</version>
```

Can I achieve this by using maven profile? something like:

```
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>normal</id>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT<version>
    </proifle>
    <profile>
        <id>build</id>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT-${timestamp}<version>
    </proifle>
</profiles>
```

so that I can build it like :

```
mvn package -P normal  // this gives me artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
or
mvn package -P build     // this gives me artifact-1.0-SNAPSHOT-${timestamp}.jar
```

if profile can solve this problem, what are the other approaches?

Comment: If you publish snapshot artifacts to a Maven repository manager like Nexus, it will ensure each build has a unique timestamp.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Though I wouldn't recommend this approach, you can use profiles for this task. Here's how it can be done:

```
<version>${projectVersion}</version>
...
<profiles>
    <profile>
        <id>normal</id>
        <activation>
            <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
        </activation>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>1.0-SNAPSHOT</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
    <profile>
        <id>build</id>
        <properties>
            <projectVersion>1.0-SNAPSHOT-${timestamp}</projectVersion>
        </properties>
    </profile>
</profiles>
```

Comment: in maven 3 this will attempt to lookup the artifact to a path in the .m2 directory that has ${projectVersion} instead of an actual version number in child pom.xml files.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Builder Number Plugin](http://mojo.codehaus.org/buildnumber-maven-plugin/usage.html) and/or evaluate the built-in [timestamp property](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Available_Variables). Anyway, your approach is **not** recommended because a SNAPSHOT has always to be up to date.